# Trouble Recovering Data From API with Async in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, async-await

I am trying to run an api in react and have the response returned as a variable. The api returns the title of a given webpage.

**DETAILS**
The api uses the following URL {with a website url appended to the end}
http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/

A manual submission of this URL http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/www.antstand.com/ will result in "Antstand the bamboo laptop stand" being displayed in the browser. I am trying to use this api to set variable in my app.

**MY CURRENT CODE**

```
 async function titleAPI(props) {
        const baseUrl = 'http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/'
        const response = await fetch(baseUrl + props)
        const data = await response
        console.log('FUNCTION OUTPUT: ',data)
        return data
      }
      titleAPI(myUrl).then(console.log)
```

On running the code my unexpected ouptut is below (I was expecting : "Antstand the bamboo laptop stand")

```
FUNCTION OUTPUT:  
Response {type: "cors", url: "http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/www.antstand.com/", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
type: "cors"
url: "http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/www.antstand.com/"
redirected: false
status: 200
ok: true
statusText: "OK"
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
__proto__: Response
```

I think Cors refers to a cross origin error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body: (...)` and `type:'cors'` means you are getting opaque response because of CORS. Either send 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' to your origin ( or * for all origins ), or configure proxy on frontend to change `origin` header of all requests so that server could not receive it as CORS. axios has options to configure [proxy](https://github.com/axios/axios#config-defaults). [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) also provides mechanism to configure proxy in development environment.

Answer (score 0):

try this way it's display your expecting result 
"Antstand the bamboo laptop stand" show

```
 const titleAPI=async props =>{
        const baseUrl = 'http://textance.herokuapp.com/title/'
        const url = baseUrl + props
        const response = await fetch(url,{
            method:'GET',
            mode:"cors",
            credentials:"same-origin",
            cache:"no-cache",
            headers:{
                "Content-Type":"application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
            },
            redirect:"follow",
            referrer:"no-referrer"
        })
        let data = await response.text()
        return data
    }    
titleAPI('www.antstand.com/').then(data=>console.log(data))
```